# BeautifulSoup 4 with fieldset

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, fieldset

I was working on a scraper I came across

`BeautifulSoup("<fieldset> some html </fieldset>")`

This gives an error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

**Code**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content)
categories = soup.findAll('fieldset')

for category in categories:
    print category
    category = BeautifulSoup(category)
```

printing `category` I got

```html
<fieldset>
<a class="box" href="http://example.com">
<img src="http://example.png" alt="" />
</a>
</fieldset>
```

**Stacktrace**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 40, in <module>
    print get_channels_list()
  File "scraper.py", line 22, in get_channels_list
    category = BeautifulSoup(category)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\BeautifulSoup.py", line 1522, in __init__
    BeautifulStoneSoup.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\BeautifulSoup.py", line 1143, in __init__
    markup = markup.read()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please provide the *full* traceback of your error and *working code* that reproduces the error. `BeautifulSoup("<fieldset> some html </fieldset>")`, by itself, doesn't run because there is no import statement. You could have set `BeautifulSoup = None` elsewhere, or perhaps you are running *other* code that results in a `None` return value being called.

Comment: added stacktrace, please let me know if you know anything

Comment: You already have a `BeautifulSoup` element object, why are you passing it to `BeautifulSoup()` *again*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a `BeautifulSoup` element, you don't need to pass it to `BeautifulSoup()` *again*. The `str()` representation of such elements produces prettified HTML, but you do not have a string.

Simply continue working with the fieldset:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content)
categories = soup.findAll('fieldset')

for category in categories:
    # do something with the fieldset object.
```

I notice that you are using BeautifulSoup version 3. You really want to upgrade to BeautifulSoup 4; version 3 was discontinued 3 years ago and contains bugs long since addressed in BeautifulSoup 4:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Also see the [BeautifulSoup 3 section in the BeautifulSoup 4 documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#id18).

Comment: Thanks. the problem was i didn't use `from bs4` before, i was getting empty set when selecting a sub list, so i thought it was problem with fieldset, and tried to use `BeautifulSoup` again on child element. Now it is working fine after i added `from bs4`